# difference between return deferred.promise; and return deferred.promise();

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying promises in my Angular application, and found the behaviour different with a slight difference in the code...

Can somebody throw some light, for better understanding.

Difference between

```
return deferred.promise;  // This is working for me.
```

and

```
return deferred.promise(); // This is not resolving the promise
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In angularjs, the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service has promise as a property not as a method that is why the first one is working and second is not.

I think your console might have an error like `TypeError: diferred.promise is not a function`

- [The Deferred API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api)

---

Where as in jQuery the [deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) [object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) has a method named [promise()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) so you need to invoke `deferred.promise();`, I think you have confused between those 2